# Changing HTTP Port from 80 to another

Tags: php, apache, http

I am trying to make HTTP calls to my server but it is my understanding that HTTP calls are made from port 80. But my server is port 7430. How can I write a php script to change it so I can make the HTTP calls? I am new to this and trying to figure it out thanks

EDIT: this is the php script called test.php I wrote and it doesnt seem to be working

```
<?php 
   $file = fopen ("http://localhost:7430/herp/derp.json", "r");
   if (!$file) {
   echo "<p>Unable to open remote file.\n";
   exit;
   }
?>
```

Its suppose to get a JSON response. and from Javascript I make the http get request http://localhost:7430/herp/test.php. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `http://server.domain.tld:7430/herp/derp.php`

Comment: yes I understand that. I was wondering what I need to write in that PHP file. Any example I can look at?

Comment: Seriously, just write your URL like that. That's the point of a URL, it's uniform. No translation necessary.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that. I am trying to figure out what I need to put in the php file. I am relatively new to this

Comment: @Sammitch could you please see the edit with the php script? am i on the right path?

Answer (score 0):

To make HTTP calls from PHP you would use the URLs [directly](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) for simple stuff or [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for more advanced stuff. When accessing those URLs simply specify the port after domain.

On the other hand, to change the ports your server is listening to cannot be done from PHP, it will require changing webserver (such as [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html))  configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your response! In the PHP file I create and put in my server, do I just say allow_url_fopen: true . is that all i need?

Comment: Could you please see the edit I made with the php script? am i on the write track?

Comment: Rajesh K It looks ok to me! If it does not work then it is probably diabled in your PHP and you should look at PHP config.